# Setting colour on point cloud data from raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, lidar, visualisation, aerial-photography

I was reading this article: [14 ways to take charge of lidar data](http://blog.safe.com/2013/10/14-ways-to-take-charge-of-lidar-data/).

Number 12 states that you can change the colour of your point-cloud data by using a raster image. Does anyone know the process for doing this within ArcGIS?

I am looking for a way to make the visualization of lidar data really pop and I have high resolution aerial photography that I could use.

Comment: linking related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138611/assigning-rgb-values-from-geotiff-image-to-lidar-data-using-r/140201#140201

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create a TIN based on your LIDAR data, and use the TIN as base height for your high res aerial photograph (in ArcScene, add the image, right click on it, properties > base height). Maybe you can directly use the LAS as base height, but I am not sure.